# British English alternative term for Chinese Whispers

Tags: synonyms

Chinese Whispers, in British English, would be broadly recognised as a game that children play where the starting person whispers a word or phrase to another person. This is in turn whispered to another person. By chaining these together you will find that after several attempts the phrase has changed dramatically.

The [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) seems to have a similar definition. There is also [an example of this in this classic episode of The Simpsons](https://youtu.be/o_o7UfqkNuU).

It is also a useful metaphor in business where a process has many steps, has many people involved, and the original message becomes confused.

However the term seems needlessly nationally dependent and I would like to avoid using it in particular.

In US English this game seems to be sometimes referred to as Telephone, however anecdotally in British English this name would not be widely recognised and potentially contextually confusing.

I am looking for a word, term or phrase that is similar in meaning to the metaphorical usage of the game.

Comment: I recall there was a term we used for this, in the 60s in the Louisville KY area, but it's not coming to me.  I don't think it was "telephone" or something Chinese.

Comment: 'Needlessly nationally dependent' - possibly.  But surely the premise of the game is that you are passing on a sequence of sounds (in a language) you do not understand.  In my case that allows an enormous number of options.  *Chinese* Whispers is what I've always called it.

Comment: I suppose you could go for a literal descriptor - *Audio Scrambling*, or something along those lines...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers#Alternative_names could be useful.  If the British don't know of another name for this game, you're probably just out of luck.

Comment: You could call it "Pass it on", which is what children say when playing the game. Or maybe refer to it as a "Whispering Gallery" (though I think the point of the Whispering Gallery at St. Paul's Cathedral is that you hear the words *clearly!*) I don't think there's anything disparaging about the term "Chinese Whispers". It's certainly not as bad as "The China virus". We pass *that* on too!

Comment: We (UK) also have French windows but we don't think of France when we pass through them.

Comment: In the US, rather than Telephone, I've always heard *a game of telephone*. If unfamiliar with the term, you'd still get the idea it's a game. As for slurs, I'd prefer to avoid them. What makes Chinese Whispers, Chinese? I've heard of chaos referred to as a Chinese fire drill, and how can that be but a slur?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: See [Is “Chinese whispers” racist?](https://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2006/05/23/is-chinese-whispers-racist/) One post there that I agree with: *Chinese Whispers is derived from the Chinese language being unintelligible to non-speakers, it’s origin has nothing to do with any negative judgement of Chinese people themselves. The phrase is similar to “It’s all Greek to me” or “Double Dutch”. It simply means the words in the game Chinese Whispers can’t be understood.*

Comment: There is also a version called "Rumors"...

Comment: See also [**generation loss** and **degradation**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/580050/idiom-or-better-yet-a-word-for-loss-of-fidelity-by-copying/580051#580051) and the example of the game of telephone there.

Answer (score 2):

I was watching an Australian children's TV show called [Bluey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7678620) with my son the other day, and towards the end of Season 2 there is an episode called [Dunny](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13303720/) in which they play a game very similar to what I would call Chinese Whispers but they called it:

> [Pass it on](https://youtu.be/OLjtbavBzvo?t=0)

I'm not sure if it's an Australian term or one made up for the show. I note that [Old Brixtonian](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/349094/old-brixtonian) referred to it as that too [in their comment too](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562931/british-english-alternative-term-for-chinese-whispers/591935#comment1391961_562931).

Answer (score 0):

If it's email or instant messaging, I like "email charades". Not the same as Chinese Whispers, but the same effect on the end user

Comment: To me "email charades" doesn't conjure up the same type of confusion that comes from Chinese whispers.

Answer (score 0):

The two correct terms that genuinely describe the phenomena we usually use the phrase for are :

> imperfect data transmission over multiple iterations

or

> infidelity in memetic replication

Shame they don't exactly roll of the tongue :)

Source: as a metaphor in [Wikipedia: Chinese whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers)

Answer (score 0):

Grew up outside Boston, Worcester, MA, and no doubt I remember playing, 'telephone'.
It starts innocently, and ends so far off base and someone always wound up crying.

Comment: This was mentioned in the question as a term that is used in US English. Do you have any evidence that it's also used in British English, like the question asks?

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to find that Chinese Whispers was relatively recent and had a previous, much older name name:

OED

> **Chinese whispers** n. = **Russian scandal n**.
>
> 1964   Guardian 13 Mar. 5/6   *The children's game of ‘Chinese
> whispers’..in which whispered messages were passed around the room and
> the version which came back to the starting point bore no relation to
> the original message.*
>
> 1984   T. Augarde Oxf. Guide Word Games xviii. 167   *This is the
> basis for a game which ‘Professor Hoffmann’..calls Russian Gossip
> (also known as Chinese Whispers). The participants are arranged in a
> circle, and the first player whispers a story or a message to the next
> player, and so on round the circle. The original story is then
> compared with the final version, which has often changed beyond
> recognition.*

> **Russian scandal**  n.  **(a) a game in which a whispered message, after being passed from player to player, is contrasted in its
> original and final versions (b) gossip inaccurately transmitted.**
>
> 1861   Q. Rev. Apr. 348   *There is a game called Russian Scandal,
> which is played in this fashion:—A. tells B. a brief narrative, which
> B. is to repeat to C., and C. to D., and so on.*
>
> 1893   C. M. Yonge Girl's Little Bk. 17   *Do not repeat it [sc.
> gossip]. You will probably make Russian scandal of it, and the next
> person will add to it.*

I have never heard of "Russian Scandal" and assume that Russian was equally incomprehensible or that Russia was known for its unreliable rumours.

The latter is probably true as Russian humour had a fund of jokes based on inaccurate gossip.