# Idiom or better yet a word for loss of fidelity by copying

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word for describing the loss of fidelity or quality by repeated copying. I'm thinking of a xerox of a xerox, or a copy of a copy, or of the phenomena that happens when playing the game of telephone, where the original spoken phrase is distorted after being passed around a group of people.

Comment: I think *Star Trek TNG* and possibly other sci-fi stuff used the term "replicative fade" in relation to repetitive cloning, but the phrase draws a blank on ngrams.

Comment: I've heard this called *mimeograph effect* however Google provides no sources.  I am also reminded of the movie *Multiplicity* where there is a copy-of-copy clone who is, well, comic relief.  Certainly this phenomenon is well understood, so what's the name for it?

Comment: @stevesliva And all the people born in recent years are scratching their heads wondering if you made up the word *"mimeograph"*.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket And they're probably mispronouncing it with 3 syllables instead of 4, too.

Comment: @shoover - A mime-o-graph would be writing using mimes, presumably after they've been rendered unable to move somehow. While one can see where that would be tempting, I believe its illegal in most jurisdictions.

Comment: There are two types of information loss here: a photocopy just becomes more blurry overall, where in a game of telephone a word changes, but the person who heard the sentence and made the mistake has a precise sentence in mind, and if they told you the sentence it would still be a perfectly grammatical sentence containing no evidence of degradation except when compared to the original. Are you looking for one type over the other?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yeah, I'm old.  My guess would be "mimeograph" was used because the quality of reproduction was lower than with "xerox."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you make copies of copies, the quality will progressively **degrade**. This **degradation** is known as **generation loss**.

**degrade** (v.)

> To lower to an inferior or less effective level
>
> *Degrade the image quality*  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degrade)

> Lower the quality of; cause to deteriorate.
>
> *Repeaters clean up and amplify the degraded signal.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/degrade)

**generation loss** (n.)

> **Generation loss is the loss of quality between subsequent copies or transcodes of data.** Anything that reduces the quality of the
> representation when copying, and would cause further reduction in
> quality on making a copy of the copy, can be considered a form of
> generation loss. File size increases are a common result of generation
> loss, as the introduction of artifacts may actually increase the
> entropy of the data through each generation.
> ...
> Successive generations of photocopies result in image **distortion** and **degradation**. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss)

---

> In the past, this always involved combining images from two or more
> pieces of film onto one. However, **each time you copy an image, its
> quality degrades**, much like making a photocopy of a photocopy of a
> photocopy. [Ron Miller; *Digital Art*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Digital_Art/wWvjG9iLKO8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=image%20fidelity%20degrades%20with%20each%20copy&pg=PA97&printsec=frontcover)

> Furthermore, **photocopies degrade** in quality over generations. [Gary
> Marchionini; *Information Seeking in Electronic Environments*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Information_Seeking_in_Electronic_Enviro/cYOHgr18DSQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=photocopies%20degrade&pg=PA176&printsec=frontcover)

> Another factor that should be taken into consideration is
> "**generation**." Photocopies do lose a certain amount of detail. In a
> first generation photocopy this loss of detail might amount to little
> more than an annoyance, but by the third or fourth generation copy the
> loss of detail might already preclude an examination. [Jay Levinson;
> *Questioned Documents*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Questioned_Documents/_9vhht7K-qkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=photocopies%20%20generation%20loss&pg=PA106&printsec=frontcover)

> (Think of making a photocopy of a photocopy and you'll immediately
> understand **generation loss**.) [C. Hausman and P. Palombo; *Modern
> Video Production*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modern_Video_Production/D2JHYsCmgOYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22generation%20loss%22%20photocopy&dq=%22generation%20loss%22%20photocopy&printsec=frontcover)

> The children's **game of Telephone** is a classic example of how
> **messages degrade** in an analog chain of communication. [Diana Saco; *Cybering Democracy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cybering_Democracy/p0oyDlBwatYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=game%20of%20telephone%20message%20degrade&pg=PA85&printsec=frontcover)

> As anyone who has played the children's game “**telephone**" will attest,
> information will **degrade** over time, losing order and gaining
> entropy.  [David Toomey; *The New Time Travelers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_Time_Travelers_A_Journey_to_the/0cmPeKdKk1kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=game%20of%20telephone%20degrade&pg=PA209&printsec=frontcover)

> The mentor system allowed mistakes to accumulate and be passed on so
> that the quality of medical practice was **degraded** through a
> process akin to **Chinese whispers**. [Charles Buck; *Acupuncture and
> Chinese Medicine*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Acupuncture_and_Chinese_Medicine/ZBE4BAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22chinese%20whispers%22%20degrade&pg=PA202&printsec=frontcover)
>
> (No telephones back then, and where better to whisper in Chinese?)

---

*Distortion* is a related term. For images, it often refers to a twisting (think *torque*) or lack of proportionality:

**distortion** (n.)

> 1 The act of twisting or altering something out of its true, natural,
> or original state: the act of distorting
>
> *a distortion of the facts*
>
> 2 the quality or state of being distorted: a product of distorting:
> such as
>
> a. *physics*: a lack of proportionality in an image resulting from
> defects in the optical system
>
> *an image free of distortion*
>
> b. **falsified reproduction** of an audio or video signal (see SIGNAL
> entry 1 sense 4b) caused by change in the wave form of the original
> signal [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distortion)

Comment: Seems like a lot of clutter here? In general, isn't it fine to write only the answer (generation loss) and then only its definition (and here only to show it's a common term)?

Comment: @OwenReynolds I don't see how it's a bad thing to add more explanation/context. Plus they write the answer in the first sentence... if you really just want the name of the phrase, you can stop reading at the first sentence. But obviously having a lot of example sentences clarifies the meaning in the way that no amount of definition can.

Comment: @OwenReynolds A definition alone often doesn't provide nuances in how an answer is used. I try to find example that do this while also confirming or expounding on the definition (not always possible). In my short time at ELU, I've found such answers garner more upvotes. // I think *degrade/degradation* is also an answer and happens to go hand-in-hand with *generation loss*. You would probably say to a co-worker "If we make a copy of this copy, the image will probably degrade" rather than "...will suffer generation loss." If a moderator tells me I'm off base, I'll change how I answer.

Comment: @OwenReynolds The Wiki article mentions *distortion* along with *degradation*.

Comment: [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1683/) seems to agree with "degrade".

Comment: @EricDuminil That has "first generation" as well :-)

Comment: But you agree that degrade isn't THE answer, right? It's too general. Generation loss is the exact term here for "degrades because of copies of copies... ". And it's somewhat buried by being listed 2nd then followed by so much else, isn't it?

Comment: @OwenReynolds I'll leave it to others to decide if there is one right/best answer and *generation loss* is in the first line of my answer.  One example above is "Furthermore, photocopies degrade in quality over generations." If the author had written "generation loss" in a non-technical setting, I think they would only have to explain it to readers: "Furthermore, repeatedly copying photocopies will lead to generation loss, i.e., a  progressive degradation in quality."

Comment: If it helps, if you told someone in the video business that a tape had degraded, they'd ask why and say "oh, you mean generation loss". Lots of times when you look something up you wonder if people really talk that way -- I'm saying, yes, I know them, and they do.

Comment: @OwenReynolds. OK, but my point is that for the general public, *generation loss* doesn't explicitly say what the loss if *of*, which might be OK if you are already discussion degradation and loss of fidelity, but perhaps not otherwise, e.g., you look at a copy and tell someone "There's been too much generation loss."

Comment: But that's the point of [single-word/idiom] requests, right? They already have a common-language way to say it, and are looking for a more precise yet lesser-known phrase.

Comment: The OP didn't use the word *degradation* (and perhaps didn't know it applied). I thought giving both terms was appropriate, especially since they are so closely related. You of course are free to have your own answer style. *Generation loss* isn't a single word or an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

*Corruption* can occur as something is copied, e.g.

> Even the best of scribes could easily succumb to any of these errors by accident, corrupting their manuscript without knowing...

https://sites.dartmouth.edu/ancientbooks/2016/05/24/medieval-book-production-and-monastic-life

Comment: note however that corruption usually implies that the data becomes essentially completely unusable. for images i feel like it normally implies some (not necessarily all) of the image being completely unrecognizable

Comment: @somebody That's often true for people who are familiar with the term from its use with digital technology.  Outside of digital technology, the definition of "corruption" is usually more similar to "alteration".

Comment: That's talking about actual words getting changed, added, or removed. I suppose one could argue its a *similar* concept, in that the original meaning is getting "fuzzier", but I can't help but think there's a better cognitive match out there.

Comment: The question mentions the game of telephone, which involves words getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

Replicative Fading is used in biology, particularly in cloning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simulacra/Simulacrum

From Jean Baudrillard

> Simulacra and Simulation (French: Simulacres et Simulation) is a 1981
> philosophical treatise by the philosopher and cultural theorist Jean
> Baudrillard, in which the author seeks to examine the relationships
> between reality, symbols, and society, in particular the
> significations and symbolism of culture and media involved in
> constructing an understanding of shared existence.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacra_and_Simulation

Comment: Perhaps you could add some material that explains why you think this addresses the OP's question?